# Java - Filtering List Entries by Regex

Tags: java, regex, collections

My code looks like this:

```
List<String> filterList(List<String> list, String regex) {
  List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (String entry : list) {
    if (entry.matches(regex)) {
      result.add(entry);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

It returns a list that contains only those entries that match the `regex`.
I was wondering if there was a built in function for this along the lines of:

```
List<String> filterList(List<String> list, String regex) {
  List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
  result.addAll(list, regex);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Possible for `List<String>`, but think about other types.

Comment: If there was an add all that got a Predicate object than it should work for all types.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In addition to the answer from Konstantin: Java 8 added `Predicate` support to the `Pattern` class via `asPredicate`, which calls `Matcher.find()` internally:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("...");

List<String> matching = list.stream()
                            .filter(pattern.asPredicate())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Pretty awesome!

Comment: this is THE answer! :-) great, thanks for sharing. (myself, being too lazy to scroll all the way down to find your answer, I had to find out about the asPredicate the hard way :-))

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to get the matching groups directly, or do you need to apply a `Matcher` to each element of the collected `List`?

Comment: I have this code:  String regex = "[a-zA-Z]*";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        List<String> matching = list.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(pattern.asPredicate())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 28):

In java 8 you can do something like this using new [stream API](http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-java-8-streams-1):

```
List<String> filterList(List<String> list, String regex) {
    return list.stream().filter(s -> s.matches(regex)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Alas I am using Java 7.

Comment: Note: pre-compiling the regex pattern can bring significantly improve the filtering performance, the more data your list has! E.g. `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);` and `[...] .filter(s -> pattern.matcher(s).matches()) [...]`.

Answer (score 4):

Google's Java library(Guava) has an interface `Predicate<T>` which might be pretty useful for your case.

```
static String regex = "yourRegex";

Predicate<String> matchesWithRegex = new Predicate<String>() {
        @Override 
        public boolean apply(String str) {
            return str.matches(regex);
        }               
};
```

You define a predicate like the one above and then filter your list based on this predicate with a single-line code:

```
Iterable<String> iterable = Iterables.filter(originalList, matchesWithRegex);
```

And to convert the iterable to a list, you can again use Guava:

```
ArrayList<String> resultList = Lists.newArrayList(iterable);
```

Comment: How do I convert the resultList back to a List<String>? Do I have to add them one by one in a loop? This seems inefficient.