# Java Stream filter with regex not working

Tags: java, regex, java-8, java-stream, pojo

hope somebody can help me. I have a `ArrayList` of a `Invoice` class. What I'm trying to get is to filter this `ArrayList`and find the first element which one of its properties matches with a `regex`.
The `Invoice`class looks like this:

```
public class Invoice {
   private final SimpleStringProperty docNum;
   private final SimpleStringProperty orderNum;

   public Invoice{
    this.docNum = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.orderNum = new SimpleStringProperty(); 
}   

   //getters and setters
}
```

I'm filtering with this `regex` `(\\D+)` in order to find if there is any value in the `orderNum`property that hasn't the format of an integer.
So basically I'm using this stream

```
    Optional<Invoice> invoice = list
                            .stream()
                            .filter(line -> line.getOrderNum())
                            .matches("(\\D+)"))
                            .findFirst();
```

But It doesn't work. Any idea?
I've been searching and I found how to use the `pattern.asPredicate()` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31888916/4210702):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("...");

List<String> matching = list.stream()
        .filter(pattern.asPredicate())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With `List` of `Integer`, `String`, etc, but I haven't found how to do it with a `POJO`.
Any help will be much appreciated.
Nice day

Comment: java8 stream has no `matches` method, is this code valid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're almost there.

```
Optional<Invoice> invoice = list.stream()
  .filter(line -> line.getOrderNum().matches("\\D+"))
  .findFirst();
```

What's happening here is that you create a custom `Predicate` used to [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) the stream. It converts the current `Invoice` to a boolean result.

---

If you already have a compiled `Pattern` that you'd like to re-use:

```
Pattern p = …
Optional<Invoice> invoice = list.stream()
  .filter(line -> p.matcher(line.getOrderNum()).matches())
  .findFirst();
```