# Java 8 removing an item from array/array list based on regex

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a better way to achieve the following in java 8?

```
String regex = "^SACHI";
for (String temp : personalNames ) {
    if (temp.matches(regex)){
         personalNames.remove(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: `personalNames.removeIf(Pattern.compile("^SACHI").asPredicate());`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Filtering List Entries by Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797857/java-filtering-list-entries-by-regex)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
personalNames.removeIf(Pattern.compile("^SACHI").asPredicate());
```

You could also use the simpler

```
personalNames.removeIf(s -> s.matches("^SACHI"));
```

but it will perform `Pattern.compile("^SACHI")` under the hood, for every element in the worst case. Note that the `Pattern` created by `compile` is immutable and can be shared, hence, you could also create it only once, like

```
static final Pattern REMOVAL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^SACHI");
```

and use it like

```
personalNames.removeIf(REMOVAL_PATTERN.asPredicate());
```

---

`asPredicate()` uses `find()` instead of `matches()`, but since your pattern has the `^` anchor, it makes no difference. The method `asMatchPredicate()` for getting a predicate using `matches()` has been added in JDK 11.

---

If all you want, is to match a literal string at the beginning, you can also use

```
personalNames.removeIf(s -> s.startsWith("SACHI"));
```

which does not have the regex initialization overhead.

Comment: If I use `personalNames.removeIf(s -> s.startsWith("SACHI"));` , will that affect the worst case scenario?

Comment: `startsWith` does not use the regex engine, so for this specific pattern, which is just a literal match, it does not have that overhead. So if that’s all you want, `removeIf(s -> s.startsWith("SACHI")` might be the way to go. If you want a more complex pattern, use the solution of my answer.

Comment: @Holger PATTERN should be corrected as `Pattern`. There's a typo here.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala indeed

Answer (score 3):

Adding and/or removing elements from an existing container does not fit in nicely with the concepts of functional programming. More over that behavior is not thread safe in parallel and concurrent environment. Making it thread safe demands more effort too. Therefore prefer steteless lambdas to stateful lambdas as a good engineering practice. You can get the matching names by merely using filter operator. Here's how it looks.

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^SACHI");

List<String> validNames = personalNames.stream()
    .filter(PATTERN.asPredicate())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends did you need to modify existing list, or you need just get list without elements. 
In first case, you can use stream to filter non matching objects and remove them from list

```
personalNames.removeAll(
        personalNames
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> !x.matches(regex))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

In other case, you can just return new list with only matching objects

```
final List<String> matchingElements = personalNames.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.matches(regex))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

also, this code

```
for (String temp : personalNames ) {
    if (temp.matches(regex)){
        personalNames.remove(temp);
    }
}
```

will throw 
`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

Answer (score 1):

You can extract `errorProneNames` by `filtering` and removing respective error names from `personalNames` iterating `forEach`:

```
List<String> errorProneNames = personalNames.stream()
        .filter(name -> !name.matches(regex))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

errorProneNames.forEach(personalNames::remove);
```

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent:

```
for (String temp : personalNames ) {
   if (temp.matches(regex)){
     personalNames.remove(temp);
   }
}
```

and

```
personalNames.removeIf(name -> name.matches(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   String regex = "^SACHI";
   Predicate<String> f = n-> n.matches(regex);
   personalNames.stream().filter(x->f.test(x))
                         .forEach(n-> {
                          personalNames.remove(n);
                          });
```

Using `Predicate<T>` to filter out the names which do not matches to `String regex`.
`test(T t)`
evaluates this predicate on the given argument.

Comment: @NicoHaase , sure